# How to validate Date value in ISO Standard format for Instant type field using JsonFormat annotations or any other spring date annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-time, iso, date

I am trying to validate a valid date format for an `Instant` field in Java using the `ISO` pattern `pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")` and I am getting an error stating `JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type java.time.Instant from String \"2019-11-25T14:43:22.602Z\"` Can anyone help me, to validate date for Instant type field using annotations.

This is how I have given in the code:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING ,pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
private Instant processingEndDate;
```

or

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
private Instant processingEndDate;
```

Value and format I have used for this `Instant` Type, which is not getting parsed.

```
Sample value: 2019-11-25T14:43:22.602Z

Format I used:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

Comment: @deHaar of course it's formattable without converting to a LocalDateTime. Instant.toString() does exactly that. And Instant.parse() does the inverse. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: you don't need any annotation. That's the default format used by Spring Boot, unless you use a really old version, or you explicitly removed dependencies.

Comment: @JBNizet you're right, but the restriction is a UTC date-time, which is present here... Thanks.

Comment: @deHaar nope, still incorrect: https://ideone.com/BbZYL1.

Comment: @JBNizet Hmm... But why do the [JavaDocs of `public static Instant parse(CharSequence text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) state *The string must represent a valid instant in UTC and is parsed using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.*?

Comment: If I remove the annotations and pass the value in the format of `20191120` which is `yyyymmdd` then it is taking the value and giving me an incorrect ISO date in output of mongoDB such as `1970-08-22 16:23:51 000`. Date sent is `20190231`
Received processing date as `1970-08-22` in ISO format @JBNizet

Comment: How do I make sure that it only takes ISO format and not any other format for this Instant field validation ? @deHaar

Comment: Add a tag or mention of which JSON processing library you are using. Perhaps *Jackson*? If so, say so.

Answer (score 4):

## Use the `Z` — Do not ignore it

Do not put quote marks around the `Z`. Change `'Z'` to `Z`. Use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. Your quote marks leave the `Z` character unprocessed, ignored.

But that `Z` character provides vital info: it means an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
@JsonFormat( shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING , pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" )
private Instant processingEndDate
```

## Try the defaults

Also, you may not need to specify the formatting pattern at all. This format is the standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. Your format is the specific default for `java.time.Instant`.

So, while I do not know your particular JSON processing library, I suggest you try not specifying a format at all. See if the defaults get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, but adding the `timeZone` fixed it for me, to get the correct date. So in that way only ISO default pattern date is forced to be passed and not any other format than the one specified.

Answer (score 2):

**Adding the `timezone` for the @JsonFormat annotation fixed it.**

**[Answer]**

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING ,pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone = "UTC")
private Instant processingEndDate;
```

Comment: See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59109057/642706). The `Z` means UTC in the input string, but is being ignored because of the single-quote marks around the `Z` in the formatting pattern, `'Z'`. Your solution here is a workaround for a broken formatting pattern. Better to just **fix the formatting pattern** than use a workaround needlessly.